# Returning multiple comma delineated column header values in excel

Tags: excel-formula

My dataset:

[image]

I've got data sorted like this, however, I'd like to have a single cell that displays data like any of the below options. I've listed them in order of preference on my part.

1. UT (4), CO (2), NY (1) --- basically the column header with the value in parenthesis in decending order (most ideal)
2. UT, CO, NY --- same idea without the value count, still decending order
3. CO, NY, UT -- basically just a list.

So far I have **two formulas** that only return the first column.

**Formula 1:**

```
=IF(COUNTA($U2:$BS2)=0,"",INDEX($U$1:$BS$1,MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(ISBLANK($U2:$BS2),0),0)))
```

**Formula 2:**

```
=IF(COUNTA($U2:$BS2)=0,"",INDEX($U$1:$BS$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($U2:$BS2<>"",0),0)))
```

*Any suggestions on what I can do?*

Answer (score 0):

Edit - adding VBA function to accomplish this without having to sort the data:

```
Function StateSort(range As range)
    maxValue = 0

    'Find max value in row
    For Each cell In range
        If cell.Value > maxValue Then maxValue = cell.Value
    Next cell

    StateSort = ""
    'Loop backwards from max value down to 0
    Do While maxValue >= 0
        For Each cell In range
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                If cell.Value = maxValue Then
                    'If your state labels aren't in row 1, change the                       
                    'Cells(<row number>, cell.Column) portion below with the row number

                    StateSort = StateSort & Cells(1, cell.Column) & " (" & cell.Value & "), "
                End If
            End If
        Next cell

        maxValue = maxValue - 1
    Loop
End Function
```

The way you use this is right-click on the Sheet tab on the bottom and click "View Code", which will open the code editor.  In the menu, go to Insert > Module.  Then paste in this code in the blank space and save the workbook (as macro-enabled so the script will run).

[image]

Now you can use `=StateSort(<range>)` (pass in the range of the values) and it will format your data.

[image]

---

### Old answer (leaving as an example of sorting by row)

Turns out you can sort by row if you go to Sort > Options... > Sort left to right

So you could put the sum for each of states in a separate row.  Then you'd just sort by the sums, and use the `CONCAT` function to make the headers look correct.  ex: `=CONCAT("UT (", A4, ")")` where A4 is the cell with the sum for the state will give you `UT (4)`.

Full example:

Here's the initial data with the sum and label rows:

[image]

Here you can see the formulas in rows 7 and 8:
[image]
[image]

Then select the area you want to sort and go to Sort > Options... Sort left to right.  Select Row 7 (in this example) to sort by:

[image]

[image]

And your final sorted data:

[image]

Comment: This example actually sorts ascending, so in the second-to-last image you'd want the "Order" to be "Largest to Smallest" to get descending.

Comment: Hi Wounded, great idea and thanks for your response. I had no idea you could change the sort axis, however the result would be different than I was hoping for. Not your fault-- it's mine for lack of a better description. My data is setup where each row is an individual record -- i'm not trying to add up the states via column as that would be adding up multiple records. I'm trying to just display the effected states for my data record. Thanks!

Comment: Then was is the 4 in `UT (4)`? Isn't it just the sum of the column?

Comment: Ah, after reading the description I think I understand.  So you don't want to sort the cells in place, right?  You want to have the data in the table above, but then in a separate cell you want to combine that data in a sorted way?

Comment: I think you'll be looking for a code solution (instead of just in-cell formulas).  I may be able to try something out later.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones-- looking for a row by row end result that looks something like---

Comment: CA (2), FL (2), DE (1), KY (1)

Comment: KY (2), CA (1), DC (1)

Comment: AL (1), FL (1), KY (1)

Comment: My formula in the original post returns the first state record, so in my first example here, i would get a result of "CA", however unfortunately I have no idea how to make it return multiple records.

Comment: Updated with a VBA function to do this.  Let me know if this helps.